# How to follow clean code rules in case of pathing data model or other issues

Tags: ios, swift

I really like clean code design and different architecture patterns and solutions like VIPER and etc. I like single responsibility rule and SOLID principles. But sometimes we need to make a correction related to a user data which can involve us to the situation when we need to write extra code to path/fix some issue which could potentionaly break code design and add some complexity of code understanding by other users.

Let me provide an example:
I have a screen where I can create exercise with name and a screen where I display all created exercises.

1. I have an entity called `Exercise` which is an `NSManagedObect`.
2. When entering Create Exercise screen my code creates an empty `Exercise` record in database which potentially cause an issue if app crash in case we don't handle such situation.
3. If I enter a name and will save this exercise all is ok but in case app crashes we will have an empty exercise in data base.

I would say that the crash could be initiated by iOS or some other background process not by my create exercise method.

Let's say now we released this app to the store and some users have this zombie records in their database because of some unexpected crashes.

Before this my code was designed following all clean code rules but with some potential "zombie" issues.

So now I need somehow correct this issue. For example at start I can run a method to check if there are any exercises without names. Never mind it's just technical solution how to check those zombies I don't need answer here. I just want to ask how code should be written using clean code styles.

Because I will add extra code to drop zombies and actually it's not a part of my wonderful architecture.

Do I need to write some Class where I need to store these paths/fixes function or do I need to follow some other rules as well.

Probably it's ok to have one function which will be called `removeAllZombies` at start of app placed in the app delegate, but even then I don't like. But if we say for a lot of potential paths then the code could be a mess.

I know it's also a part of testability issue, but sometimes we could not cover all the issues by tests and pathing data model on the fly adding a lot of extra line to view controllers, presenters, services and etc is a very quick way to break a project and project code design rules.

Comment: If you use Core Data, you don't need to save the empty record at all. You can wait and only call `managedObjectContext.save()` when the record has a name. And since you like SOLID, I recommend also reading about [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

Comment: Hi @Yonat! thank you for your comment. I agree that following all the good patterns and principles should be main things. But sometimes we have a lot of people involved to the project and mistake could be found later when the code is in the production state already, and we need to make some hot paths fixes. So originally my question is about how to add such fixes which actually just workaround in the code and if we say about places where we should store this workaround code we probably also should follow some rules just not to bring a code to mess.

Comment: A common solution is to have a `Storage` class that is responsible for creating, saving, and cleaning up stored objects.